# Why is App_Crypto not building in frame system runtime

Tags: pallet, runtime, grandpa

When building I am running into this error:

```
error: cannot find macro `format` in this scope
    --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: consider importing one of these items:
             alloc::format
             scale_info::prelude::format
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `std`
    --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `std`
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `String`
    --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_public_common_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: consider importing one of these items
     |
  42 |     use alloc::string::String;
     |
  42 |     use codec::alloc::string::String;
     |
  42 |     use scale_info::prelude::string::String;
     |

  error[E0412]: cannot find type `String` in this scope
    --> /Users/jackson/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/22d40c7/primitives/finality-grandpa/src/lib.rs:43:2
     |
  43 |     app_crypto!(ed25519, GRANDPA);
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
     |
     = note: this error originates in the macro `$crate::app_crypto_pair_functions_if_std` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
  help: consider importing one of these items
     |
  42 |     use alloc::string::String;
     |
  42 |     use codec::alloc::string::String;
     |
  42 |     use scale_info::prelude::string::String;
     |
```

From first glance it looks like these errors are resulting from the same problem. However since I don't know where the error is occurring I am not sure where to test solutions. I have seen other posts about this here, but they all have different root causes and different solutions. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Try clearing cache and update Rust and the toolchain and then compile that fresh temmplate

Comment: Please provide the full source code such that we can reproduce this.  Generally looks like an issue with std. This code is AFAIK only intended to work in a `no_std` environment.

Comment: Had the same error when someone added a pallet to the Cargo.toml of a runtime but not added it to the `std` feature. (Shawn's tool didn't pick this up but maybe because I was running it against cumulus)

Answer (score 1):

As Oliver mentioned above, the issue seems to be that you are leaking `std` features into the `no_std` environment.

You can use a tool like this to try and detect issues like this for you:

https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-toml-lint

Otherwise, go through the Cargo.toml files you changed, and make sure that everything is being imported correctly with the appropriate feature flags being enabled.

Comment: This is cool. I wonder if it could influence features that are in https://github.com/bkchr/diener/ - I _think_ (not having used this or your tool myself yet) they could be related, although diener is for modifications beyond linting, adding a linting option could make the tool more broadly useful?

Comment: In any case - it should be on the awesome list: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/awesome-substrate/pull/82